# how to match exactly one word among the others in REGEX 'or'(|) condition

Tags: java, json, regex

I am aware that there are similar questions to this but none of them seem to match my requirement. I am new to regex and still learning. I appreciate Any help with following problem.
I have following input json data. PS: I have simplified the actual data for better understanding of my problem.
1.

```json
{
  "name": "abc",
  "response": {
    "postback": "UNIQUE-a651-95e4834b63cc",
    "text": "testing"
  },
  "remarks": "get keyword"
}
```

2. 

```json
{
  "name": "abc",
  "response": {
    "postback": "a651-95e4834b63cc",
    "text": "testing"
  },
  "remarks": "get keyword"
}
```

Regex

```
(UNIQUE)|(\"(response|someothedata|otherdata|somedata)\")
```

I want to get which of these keywords is matched. here it gets trickier if 'UNIQUE' field is present it should stop right there and not match any further.
I am using following java code

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("(UNIQUE)|(\"(response|someothedata|otherdata|somedata)\")")  
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);  
if(matcher.find()){
  match = matcher.group();
}
```

for both input json, matcher.group() returns 'response'

I want to achieve following :

for 1. group() to return 'UNIQUE'
for 2. to return 'response' i.e, only if 'UNIQUE' not present

Note: once I get the matched word(match) there are few actions to be done based on that, so that can't be compromised

can anyone please help me how I can somehow prioritize 'UNIQUE' keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(UNIQUE|\"(?:response|someothedata|otherdata|somedata)\")");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);  
if(matcher.find()){
  match = matcher.group(1).replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EUoAip/1). Details:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (this moves the regex index to the end of string/line)
- `(UNIQUE|\"(?:response|someothedata|otherdata|somedata)\")` - Group 1: `UNIQUE` or `"`, followed with either `response`, `someothedata`, `otherdata`
  or `somedata` and then `"`

You are matching a single occurrence of a pattern, and that means it does not matter for you whether the match is first or last. That is why adding `.*` and grouping `UNIQUE` and `"(?:response|someothedata|otherdata|somedata)"` in one capturing group will work. The only "problem" is that the `response`, etc. words will come with double quotes on both ends, so you can safely remove them with `.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "")`.

Comment: Thank you for understanding the requirements and giving the solution. But there is an issue, this works only when input json is in single line. I have updated the question and please check out  [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EUoAip/2) . ps: sorry I should have mentioned input data properly.

Comment: @SavinayaShetty Use `"(?s).*(UNIQUE|\"(?:response|someothedata|otherdata|somedata)\")"`